# Representing a JS objects reference by a string

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a situation where I need to be able to compare if 2 objects are the same, but the comparison needs to be a string comparison.

**To be clear, I cannot use `const a = {}; a === a;` to compare**

The below function `objectReferenceToString` is what I am looking for, and it would behave as such:

```
const a = { foo: "bar" }
const b = { foo: "bar" }

console.log(objectReferenceToString(a) === objectReferenceToString(a)) // true
console.log(objectReferenceToString(a) === objectReferenceToString(b)) // false
```

Notice how the last `console.log` logs `false`. I do not want the string to represent the *content* of the object but it's *reference*.

Comment: What benefit would `objectReferenceToString` have when you get the same behaviour by comparing the object references themselves? But if for some reason this is required, I'm pretty sure you can't do it with a function that gives you a string (or other primitive). What actual problem are you trying to solve - because there's almost certainly another way.

Comment: I'm confused by your last sentence, can you clarify?  What about an object reference allows you to compare two different objects?  If you compare object references of two different objects, it's always going to be false.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(a === b)`. It already does what you want. It returns `false`. Can you elaborate why this doesn't work for your?

Comment: I do know exactly how object comparisons work (if you read the question you would have seen), and I need a way to compare if 2 objects are the same _with a string_, and not by comparing the actual objects. The objects have no identifier, and I cannot add one. I absolutely not see the issue with this question. And yes I'm 100% aware this is by no means something that should be used regularly but in my specific use-case it might be an option, and I'm curious if there is a solution. I have a very specific question which perfectly describes exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @GabrielPetersson It would help (or at least preempt those comments) if you would name your use case in the question. Too many askers claim constraints ("*the comparison needs to be a string comparison*") that are not actually given, so to prevent the XY problem it's always good to state why you're restricted and what you need this for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a string to represent an object reference, use the object reference itself. Cheap and simple. `a === a` and `a === b` will give the desired results.

If you do need this for some kind of serialisation (that should deserialise into the same object graph?), a `WeakMap` is the way to go:

```
const refs = new WeakMap();
let count = 0;
function objectReferenceToString(obj) {
    let ref = refs.get(obj);
    if (!ref) refs.set(obj, ref = '$'+count++);
    return ref;
}
```

Comment: Aa clever! Maps can have an object as a key, which can be mapped to strings, which solves the problem.